# Finding an exact string

Tags: ansible

Trying to make sure an exact string exists for a when condition, but right now trying to get the function working in a simple playbook, but can't seem to get it to work.  Also tried escaping characters too

I have tried different variations and tried switching to " instead of ' and vise-versa

my.conf

```
JAVA_HOME="/opt/java/hotspot/64_bit/jdk1.8.0_201/"
JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/hotspot/64_bit/jdk1.8.0_201/
JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/hotspot/64_bit/jdk1.8.0_202/
JAVA_HOME="/opt/java/hotspot/64_bit/jdk1.8.0_202/"
SUN_JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/hotspot/64_bit/jdk1.8.0_201/
SUN_JAVA_HOME="/opt/java/hotspot/64_bit/jdk1.8.0_201/"
BAE_JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/hotspot/64_bit/jdk1.8.0_201/
BAE_JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/hotspot/64_bit/jdk1.8.0_202/
BAE_JAVA_HOME="/opt/java/hotspot/64_bit/jdk1.8.0_201/"
BAE_JAVA_HOME="/opt/java/hotspot/64_bit/jdk1.8.0_202/"
```

playbook

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: read the passwd file
    shell: cat /tmp/my.conf
    changed_when: False
    register: user_accts

  - name: set regex pattern
    set_fact:
      regex_pattern: ".*^JAVA_HOME=\"/opt/java/hotspot/64_bit/jdk1.8.0_201/\"$"
  - name: a task that only happens if the user exists
    when: user_accts.stdout |match('{{regex_pattern}}')
    debug: msg="user hillsy exists"
```

I want to make sure it finds this JAVA_HOME="/opt/java/hotspot/64_bit/jdk1.8.0_201/"
and if I change this line to 
JAVA_HOME="/opt/java/hotspot/64_bit/jdk1.8.0_209/"
it doesn't find it

Comment: you have to use with_items user_accts.stdout -- this will print all the values at once. You need to match these values. Also you should use search string regex is not needed if you are only looking for 1.8.0_201

Comment: Sorry for the confusion I'm wanting to get that exact string so I don't get the other ones in the example above.  I tried when: with item, when: with_item, and with_item: but not getting it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm wanting to get that exact string so I don't get the other ones in the example above

If you are looking for that exact string, then you don't need a regular expression

```
- debug:
    msg: it matches

  # because an empty list is considered "false", if none of the lines
  # are equal, this will not run
  when: user_accts.stdout_lines | select('eq', the_string) | list
  vars:
    the_string: JAVA_HOME="/opt/java/hotspot/64_bit/jdk1.8.0_201/"
```